# How to run JUnit 5 Test suite for differents environments [micronaut 1.2.5]?

Tags: java, junit5, micronaut

I have 3 differents types of environments : local, staging and integration. Each of those environments(application-local.yml, application-staging.yml, application-integration.yml) has some own properties for example proxies.

For every environments i created differents packages : **com.myapp.local; com.myapp.staging; com.myapp.integration.**. Into each packages they are differents tests.

How can i then write a test suite in micronaut, where a suite run for one package and one specific environment?

Ex: Test Suite 1 run for package **com.myapp.local** with environment **local**

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to design your unit tests to be environment-specific. Usually you'd have a environment-agnostic set of tests; they should pass in any environment.

Comment: But here i have some proxies involved. And integration tests need a different proxy as when the dev tested it on its machine.

Comment: Have you considered using Wiremock? It would allow you to do away with proxies by predefining responses for each of your test cases' queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i then write a test suite in micronaut, where a suite run for
>   one package and one specific environment?

It depends on some factors that you haven't described but one piece is that if you only want to run tests for a certain package, if you are using Gradle you can do something like this...

```
./gradlew test --tests com.myapp.local.*
```

Answer (score 0):

To activate different profiles you can use the environment variable 
`MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` and set it to your profile.

I guess you have different tests tasks. You can set any variable via gradle by

```
systemProperty "micronaut.environments", "local"
```

in case you want to go further, you can

```
includeTestsMatching "com.myapp.local.*"
```